# Chrome Extension Signup: Authorisation vs Authentication vs Cookies

Tags: google-chrome, identity

I'm working on creating a user-friendly signup process for my Chrome extension. The aim is to minimise user effort in downloading and using the extension, while ensuring data security.

My current approach involves using chrome.identity and invoking chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive:true}) upon the extension's first install. This method simplifies API calls by using Google as an intermediary, only forwarding them to my servers after successful HTTP response. This seems quite an awkward approach.

However, it appears more straightforward than the complexities of OpenID, which would require users to repeatedly log in to access the extension.

Another option is to create trial accounts. This involves temporarily storing sensitive data on the user's computer and changing API calls to Storage API calls until full authentication is complete, potentially through my website. This process, including email and password verification, takes about one and a half minutes.

I am seeking advice on the most efficient and secure method to onboard new users to my Chrome extension. What would be your recommendation for my situation?